# Installing Texlive and Texmaker

Tags: installing

I'm trying to install Texlive and Texmaker.
So I ran this command for installing Texlive:

```
./install-tl
```

After that, the installation guide advises adding PATH, MANPATH and INFOPATH:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

But I don't understand how, I searched for `/home/.profile` or `/home/.bashrc`
and I'm quite lost.
What is the difference with symlinks ? And what does adding PATH, MANPATH and INFOMATH do ?

And lastly, for installing Texmaker, I ran `sudo dpkg -i texmaker*.deb` and I got:

```
(Reading database ... 180399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack texmaker_5.0.3_debian_9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking texmaker (5.0.3-1) over (5.0.3-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texmaker:
 texmaker depends on libqt5concurrent5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5concurrent5 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on qtbase-abi-5-7-1; however:
  Package qtbase-abi-5-7-1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package texmaker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texmaker
```

I guess I have to run:

```
sudo apt install liqt5concurrent5
sudo apt install qtbase-abi-5-7-1
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Add the three path lines to your `.profile`, log out and in again to activate it. You can verify by running `which latex` afterwards. For texmaker, it is very likely that texmaker is already in your Linux distro. Just install it using `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends  texmaker` instead of downloading the deb file manually. `apt` takes care of the dependencies. The `--no-install-recommends` part make sure that you do not also get an extra LaTeX installation from your Linux (one that is often out dated)

Comment: The various PATHs are environment variables which tell your shell where to "look for" executables (PATH), manual pages (MANPATH), and info pages (INFOPATH), so that when your shell tries to execute "pdflatex" (for instance) it "looks" for it in the appropriate place. They are set, as environment variables are generally, by adding them to a file. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables may be helpful generally on how to set environment variables. If the relevant file does not exist in your home directory, just create it.

Comment: Just don't just add it to `.bashrc`, then TeXMaker cannot find LaTeX if you start TeXMaker from a menu or by double clicking on a `.tex` file.

Comment: That's actually a question for one of the Unix related stackexckange sites, like http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://askubuntu.com. Anyway, there are enough Linux users here which can answer the question and as it is about LaTeX installation it is still on-topic here (but also on the sites mentioned above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the three lines inside `~/.profile` also known as `$HOME/.profile` which both point to `/home/<yourusername>/.profile`. The path `/home/.profile` is wrong. Linux is a multi-user OS where each user has a subdirectory under `/home`. MS Windows took this  principle over with its `c:\users\` directory.

Note that you need to reopen a new command line windows/shell in order to make this lines active in the shell. Graphical tools will only take advantage of it after restarting the window manager, i.e. by logging out and in. Of course, you can do this the Windows way and just reboot the whole machine, but that is basically never needed for Linux.

---

By adding the LaTeX binary directory to the `PATH` environment variable you can just type `latex` in your command line window instead of the full path `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/i386-linux/latex`. The OS searches in all directory mentioned in `PATH` for the given executable.

Similar are `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH`, but for the `man` (stands for "manual") or the similar `info` program. It allows them to find the help files of the LaTeX binaries, so you can use the commands `man latex` or `info latex` to read the manual and info pages in the command line. Personally, I basically never needed them, as the standard help text of the `latex` executable is enough.

---

Also you stated, that you used `./install-tl` to install TeXLive. Did you switched to the super-user (root) before, e.g. using `sudo -i`? As normal user you won't have write permission to `/usr/local/`.

About the TeXmaker installation, which is actually an own question, I agree that you need to install the two mentioned packages as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Okay, now it's more understandable.
I forgot to put it but yes I ran it with `sudo`:

    `sudo ./install-tl`

But without `-i`

Comment: @PandaBear: `sudo -i` gives you a login shell as root, where you then can execute commands without `sudo` for each. For single commands `sudo <command>` without `-i` is correct.